# IO.popen issue in on ruby/ rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On update ruby to 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.12 below code is not working. as I have imagemagick installed and I am able to run `identify` in command prompt.

Below code is telling me "Could not execute 'identify'. Is ImageMagick installed?"

Please suggest what is wrong in IO.popen command below. Same things were working in my older version.(i.e. ruby 1.9.2. and rails 3.2.11).

```
require 'io/console'
IO.popen("/usr/bin/identify").close
unless $? == 0
  raise "Could not execute 'identify'. Is ImageMagick installed?"
end
```

Comment: Are you certain that the user running the ruby application can access and execute the "identify" command? Often web-apps run under a server, e.g. nginx as www-data or even "nobody" and are very restricted in what they may access.

Comment: its in my config file just to confirm rmagick should work properly.